# One-Time password authentication in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I'm working on a school project where I need to develop an app similar to WhatsApp. I'm working on ejabberd but I want that when a new user registers they register only by their phone number and an SMS verification code is sent to their phone and by that they must enter the given code within a period of time so if the code is entered correctly then the user gets a registration. The problem is that I don't know how to do that because I need to customize my ejabberd server to this specific need. I've searched a lot for an article to try and understand how I can manage that but couldn't find anything. If anyone knows how to do that I'd really appreciate your help.

Thanks, lads.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any module for ejabberd that implements that feature, and a quick search did not show any result.

If you are able to implement such a feature in a language you are confortable (PHP, Python, whatever), you can implement the Web page to handle the registration request and send the SMS, then handle the code formulary and... if the user entered the correct code, send a query to ejabberd to register that account.

The only part of your web page that is specific to ejabberd is the very last step, registering the account. You can send that query to ejabberd using XMLRPC, a HTTP ReST query, or the command line "ejabberdctl" script, see
https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/#understanding-ejabberd-commands

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample OTP implementation in Erlang:

```erlang
encrypt_0([H|T], [H1|T1]) ->
        [H bxor H1 | encrypt_0(T, T1)];
encrypt_0(_, []) ->
        [].
```